# with deleting listview item from database, Android

Tags: android

Ok i have built an app like a remainder, every thing works fine but when click to delete, first deleted wrong row, then now not even work.

i now there are lot of same answer to the question, i swear i try every one i found!

there is some thing i do not know!

this code in the MainActivitey:

```
lvEvent.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


            db.deleteEvent(id);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

here is the deleting part in DataBase:

```
public boolean deleteEvent(long id){
    return ((
    db.delete(TB_EVENT, COLUMN.Id + "=" + id, null  )
    //db.delete(TB_EVENT, COLUMN.id + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id)});
    ) == 1 ) ? true : false;
}
```

also there is an adapter to populate the List View.

Comment: What kind of object is db? Also you might want to post the custom adapter for the list view.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are passing wrong `COLUMN.Id` to `deleteEvent` method. `long id` is row id of the item(not position of clicked item) that was clicked created dynamically during ListView row creation.

So you need to pass `position` to `deleteEvent` method:

```
        db.deleteEvent(position);
```

Comment: thanks, its works now, but it delete the 2nd row about what i pressed!

Comment: @GAOS: debug your code what is value of `position` when first item is clicked or when second item is click probably you will need to pass `(position-1)`

Comment: I think OP can't rely on `position` to delete the item from DB. After every deletion relative value of position will change for all the items.

Comment: @Rohit5k2: yes OP need to assign custom it to each column in db to identify record

Comment: i am sorry, what you mean by OP?